# Run-time 1004 error with substitute function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Any idea why this code is producing a run-time 1004 error?

```
Dim outputHtml As String, tbody As String

outputHtml = Right(htmlCode, Len(htmlCode) - InStr(htmlCode, "<div class=""b-campaign-stat-data b-campaign-stat-data_type_custom"">") + 1)

tbodyStart = InStr(outputHtml, "<tbody")
tbodyEnd = InStr(outputHtml, "</tbody>")

tbody = Mid(outputHtml, tbodyStart, tbodyEnd + 8 - tbodyStart)

outputHtml = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(outputHtml, tbody, "g")
```

it is the last line that is tripping it up. I've tried with `Application.Substitute` as well...

Comment: Why are you using `Substitute` rather than VBA's native `Replace` function?

Comment: Honestly? Because I didn't know it existed ... I have looked in the past (prob years ago) and thought there wasn't a native function (which I did think was weird!).

That solves my problem, although I am still curious as to why `substitute` doesn't work...

Comment: Is your text longer than 32767 characters? That's the limit for `Substitute`.

Comment: Ah - yes, it may well be. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have not declared your `tbodyEnd` variable.  Add this to your code:

```
Dim tbodyEnd As String
```

Note, you can enable the "Option Explicit" to avoid problems like this in the future.  There are two ways to do this:

1. Add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module, or
2. Go to "Tools" > "Options" and check "Require Variable Declaration" on the "Editor" tab.

Doing either of these will result in a more-meaningful warning/error when you have not declared a variable.  It will provide you with the name of the variable, which is helpful.

Comment: I agree, but tbodyEnd would be an Integer or Long.

Comment: Why would this be causing the issue? - That returns a number which is passed into the `mid()` function. I have tried returning the `tbody` and it is fine - why would this cause the `substitute` function not to work?

Comment: Then you need to use `CStr()` in your method call: `tbody = Mid(outputHtml, tbodyStart, CStr(tbodyEnd + 8 - tbodyStart))`

Comment: I have tried the suggestion of declaring `tbodyStart` and `tbodyEnd` and it has not helped.

Comment: As I have explained, the `mid()` function is operating fine and generating a string. It is the `substitute` function that is not working..

Comment: When I run it (after declaring all the missing variables), the problem is with `Mid`.

Comment: Hmm... My problem is still with `substitute`.